# Ubuntu apache SOLR can't find com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: ubuntu, java, solr

I have a problem using the data import handler with apache solr running on ubuntu 12.04 where it failes to load the mysql java driver with the error:

```
Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

However I can see that it is loading the required file as during startup it outputs the following:

```
INFO: Adding 'file:/home/ubuntu/solr-4.1.0/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar' to classloader
```

So at this point I am a bit stuck... I've also tried putting the connector in the main lib/ folder for my solr setup as well but with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by adding the required java lib file to the lib folder inside the solr